# kitchen create with vagrant-libvirt plugin

Tags: vagrant, libvirt, test-kitchen

I tried to do kitchen create with this kitchen.yml:

```
---
driver_plugin: vagrant

transport:
  name: ssh
  ssh_key: /home/aida/Documents/chef-repo/.chef/aida.pem

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
  driver_config:
    provider: libvirt
platforms:
  - name: rhel7
    driver_config:
      box: qcow-libvrit
      box_url: file:///home/aida/Documents/packer/builds/libvirt-centos7.box
    customize:
      memory: 1024
    network:
      - ['private_network', {ip: '192.168.33.33'}]
suites:
  - name: default

    run_list:
      - recipe[gtd_buildhost::default]
    attributes:
```

but I couldnt do it!

```
I got:
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.16.0)
-----> Creating <default-rhel7>...
       Bringing machine 'default' up with 'libvirt' provider...
       ==> default: Starting domain.
       ==> default: Waiting for domain to get an IP address...
       ==> default: Waiting for SSH to become available...
```

even, vagrant up is not working and I couldn't understand what is the issue!

---

So I change my kitchen.yml to:

```
---
driver_plugin: vagrant

transport:
  name: ssh
  ssh_gateway_username: vagrant
  username: vagrant
  password: vagrant
  ssh_key: /home/aida/Documents/chef-repo/.chef/aida.pem

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
  driver_config:
    provider: libvirt
platforms:
  - name: rhel7
    driver_config:
      box: qcow-libvrit
      box_url: file:///home/aida/Documents/packer/builds/libvirt-centos7.box
    vagrantfiles:
      - /home/aida/Documents/chef-solo/cookbooks/gtd_buildhost/Vagrantfile.rb


suites:
  - name: default

    run_list:
      - recipe[gtd_buildhost::default]
    attributes:
```

and it works now. But it`s strange! because some time is working and sometimes I had a same SSH connection problem

Comment: Can you please put the complete the error log?

Comment: I don't know what happened but it works now! I`ll update my question